# PyLab - changing text color and background fill color of text box

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using PyLab to make some graphs in Python. I want to make a text box that is colored magenta with black text, but cannot get the text to be black.

```
text(x, y, 'Summary', backgroundcolor = 'm', color = 'k')
```

This gives me a magenta background and then text that is almost just as pink. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: This comment is 3 years late, but I experience the same bug. Graphics written to disk (PDF, PNG) are correct, but the text is same color as background for all colors *on the display*. I'm using latest EPD (Canopy 1.3.0.1715) and MacOSX backend.

Answer (score 5):

it doesn't appear as though you're doing anything wrong:

```
In [23]: pylab.text(0.25, 0.5, 'test', backgroundcolor='m', color='r')
In [24]: pylab.text(0.5, 0.5, 'test', backgroundcolor='m', color='k')
In [25]: pylab.text(0.75, 0.5, 'test', backgroundcolor='m', color='b')
```

[alt text http://student.physics.ucdavis.edu/~rjames/test.png](http://student.physics.ucdavis.edu/~rjames/test.png)

perhaps somewhere else in your code (or matplotlib installation) the mapping from strings to colors has been corrupted?

Comment: The matplotlib might be corrupted. I tried running just this code:


    import pylab

    from pylab import *

    pylab.text(.25, .25, 'test', backgroundcolor='m', color='k')

    show()


And still get the same behavior. Weird because I downloaded the Enthought EPD Python distro thinking it would make my life easier!

Comment: @Mark: it should have, the guys over at enthought do a fantastic job.  what does using other colors for the text produce (e.g. r, b as in my example)?  what about different background colors?